# Captcha in spring mvc/security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, captcha

I need to implement a captcha for spring application.

I was researching different options, and though many recommend reCaptcha, it is very likely that we can not use it because the application would be internal (not have access to internet).

The option that convinced me was BotDetect (since SimpleCaptcha not specify anything about support for Java 1.7)

We leave authentication to spring security, so as we have not a controller with @RequestMapping("/login") i've decided to validate the captcha by an interceptor, overwriting the preHandle method.

My problem is that I am unable to retrieve the captcha from the interceptor, for some reason not included on the request.

My code is based on the documentation BotDetect (https://captcha.com/doc/java/howto/springmvc-captcha.html)

Any idea why not work? or if there is any other alternative to implement the captcha with spring security is welcome

this is my jsp:

```
<form action="/businessPortal/login" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">
            <spring:message code="IntroPage.UserName" />:
        </label>
        <input type="text"  id="userName" name="j_username" class="form-control" tabindex="1">
    </div>
    <p class="divider"></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">
            <spring:message code="IntroPage.Password" />:
        </label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" class="form-control" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <p class="divider"></p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <botDetect:captcha id="basicExampleCaptcha"/>
        <div class="validationDiv">
            <input id="captchaCodeTextBox" type="text" name="captchaCodeTextBox" value="${basicExample.captchaCodeTextBox}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
</form>
```

this is my spring security configuration:

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    ...
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessDenied"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"
        login-processing-url="/login" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <sec:logout />
</sec:http>
```

the interceptor configuration:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="validateCaptchaInterceptor"  class="com.project.backend.security.captcha.ValidateCaptchaInterceptor">
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

this is the interceptor code:

```
public class ValidateCaptchaInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ValidateCaptchaInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command){
        boolean isHuman = true;
        if(request.getRequestURL().toString().indexOf("login") != -1){
            BasicExample basicExample = (BasicExample)command;
            // validate the Captcha to check we're not dealing with a bot
            Captcha captcha = Captcha.load(request, "basicExampleCaptcha");
            isHuman = captcha.validate(request,basicExample.getCaptchaCodeTextBox());
        }
        return isHuman;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need captcha on site which is not accessible from internet?

Comment: According to what my client said, they are concerned about their own employees. I agree that makes no sense, but we had no way to convince them otherwise: S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I finally solved with a filter (not interceptor)

this is my filter and declaration (i wanted to execute this filter before FORM_LOGIN_FILTER)

```
<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    ...
    <sec:custom-filter ref="captchaFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    ...
</sec:http>

<bean id="captchaFilter" class="path.to.my.filter.CaptchaFilter" p:postOnly="false">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authFailureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authSuccessHandler" />
    <property name="restTemplate" ref="commonRestTemplate" />
</bean>
```

and this is my filter code:

```
public class CaptchaFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private static final String POST = "POST";
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
  ...
} 

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    if(request.getRequestURI().indexOf("login") != -1 && request.getMethod().equals(POST) && 
       LoginAttemptsSingleton.getInstance().getLoginAttepmts().containsKey(ipAddress) &&
       LoginAttemptsSingleton.getInstance().getLoginAttepmts().get(ipAddress) > 3){
        //Captcha validation here
    }else{
        //No captcha validation, so keep going throug next filter in chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I have question, what will be next after captcha validation, how does it redirect to login page? thanks.